# failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku, laravel-7, heroku-cli

```
> C:\xampp\htdocs\starter> git push heroku master
To https://git.heroku.com/*********.git

 ![remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/*********.git'
```

Failure to push to heroku with laravel dyno.

Comment: Try to `git pull` and then `git push` again.